# Cocos2d-x: Create sprite procedurally or a layer?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am creating a small game. The game is a puzzle game. I want to have the background in one sprite and a layer on top of it, same size as the screen.

I am not sure how I should do this, but I should not load an image if possible, I should be able to do it creating a transparent width x height image.

It seems that the way to do it is with a sprite, since LayerColor is deprecated (using cocos2d-x 3.0 beta).

What is the most reasonable way to put an invisible layer that is a node on top of the background?

I want to do this because the background can be changed in-game without affecting the pieces. If I throw the pieces on top of the background, when I change the background, the pieces will disappear.

Comment: you can still use LayerColor, and in v4.0 I'm sure there will be an equivalent functionality

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, I think you answered your question in your post. Use a Node.

How about:

```
auto backgroundNode = Node::create();
this->addChild(backgroundNode, -10);
// Add child sprites, nodes, etc to this backgroundNode to fill the background.

auto transparentNode = Node::create();
this->addChild(transparentNode, 10);
// Add child sprites, nodes, etc to this transparentNode.
```

The 10 and -10 are the zOrder. Larger zOrder is drawn on top of lower zOrder objects.

The "this" in the above code could itself be a node or layer.

Comment: No size? A layer would be the size of the screen. A node does not need one?

Comment: If you want the node to have a size, then set its contentSize. e.g.     myNode->setContentSize(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize()); But it is not necessary for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you want to change the background color without affecting the pieces, you can just add the pieces as children.

```
auto bg = LayerColor::create(Color3B(255,0,0));
bg->setTag(11);
addChild(bg);

// add pieces onto background
for(..all pieces needed..) {
   auto piece = Sprite::create(..);
   bg->addChild(bg);
}

// later on
auto bg = getChildByTag(11);
bg->setColor(Color3B(0,255,0));
```